# Reattaching [Event Procedure] in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Due to requirements to not share data between clients, I have an MS Access 2010 data base that I use to extract data from our SQL Server into a small .accdb which we then send to a client, they modify, then I load the data back to the Server.

In my 'Master' Access database (**EDIT2:** I use Access as a front end to SQL Server), I have a button that will create a client specific .accdb (**EDIT2:** This has a local table that contains the client's specific data for them to moidify). This code simply copies a template .accdb with forms, code, etc & names it appropriately for the client.

Unfortunately when this copy is made, all the event procedure connections are lost from the properties box. The code still exists in the module, though. This is a fairly well-known issue and is well documented on Google. The general solution is to go through each form & reset the properties for every form & control that needs an event, then Access will reconnect it with the existing code. That's ok, once. I'll have this copy/loss issue dozens or hundreds of times.

I found one reference from <strike>~2003</strike> March, 2004 to dynamically identify missing <strike>code</strike> (**EDIT2:** [Event Procedure] references in the properties box) & set the property to [Event Procedure] to fix this. However, when trying to identify if an object should have an event handler, the code relies on this statement

```
DLookup("EventProcedureSuffix", "EventProcedures", "EventName = '" & prpCurr.Name & "'")
```

and that generates an error 3078 saying it cannot find a table or query named 'EventProcedures' (**EDIT2:** which seems to have been a system table in the older version of Access that the code was based on). Does anyone know what happened to the 'EventProcedures' table in Access 2010? Has it been renamed, is it no longer accessible, is there a replacement?

This also begs the question of how do I fire this code in the first place. I have it on the OnOpen event of the main form that is opened when the DB is opened, but if the event handler is disconnected, that won't fire, either...

**EDIT**: Found the link to the source of the code I'm using: http://www.accessmvp.com/djsteele/Access/AA200403.zip

Comment: Can you post a link describing the issue you're having?

Comment: I must admit, I'm a bit confused by your request. The entire message above was intended to describe the issue I'm having. Is it so poorly worded that the whole thing makes no sense, or is there a particular point that isn't clear that I can expand on?

Comment: Sorry - my question was unclear.  I meant can you post a link related to "This is a fairly well-known issue and is well documented on Google". New issue for me, so I wanted to read up on it.

Comment: The `EventProcedures` table you mentioned is not a standard Access table --- it's not something which existed in Access versions prior to 2010.  If you need one, you must create and load it or import the table from the sample database you're using for guidance.

Comment: @TimWilliams Ah, got it. Here's one link.http://msmvps.com/blogs/access/archive/2008/11/11/losing-the-event-procedure-on-a-command-button.aspx Of course, now that I'm looking for it again, I can't find the dozen or so links I found this morning, but that should get you started.

Comment: @HansUp Thanks. I guess I'll have to dig into this procedure some more.

Comment: @TimWilliams here's another one: http://www.vb123.com/index.html?200403_ds_aa.htm (part of the article I linked to above)

Comment: Good grief. I'm a complete nincompoop today. The answer was right in the DB that was included in the link that I added in my first edit.  Not a good week for me to ask questions at StackOverflow...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to re-attach the Event Procedures after the fact you might try to find a method that creates a new user database in a way that preserves the Event Procedure links.

The following Access 2010 code seems to work fine for me. It creates an Access 2003 format .mdb file and then exports a Table and a Form. The form has a button with code behind it, and the button works fine when I open the form within the .mdb file.

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function CreateUserDatabase()
    Dim fd As Object  ' Office.FileDialog
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim newDbPath As String
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(2)  ' msoFileDialogSaveAs
    fd.Title = "Save User Database As..."
    fd.InitialFileName = "UserDB.mdb"
    fd.Show
    If fd.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
        newDbPath = fd.SelectedItems(1)
        If UCase(Right(newDbPath, 4)) <> ".MDB" Then
            newDbPath = newDbPath & ".mdb"
        End If
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill newDbPath
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set db = DBEngine(0).CreateDatabase(newDbPath, dbLangGeneral, dbVersion40)
        db.Close
        Set db = Nothing
        DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", newDbPath, acTable, "UserData", "UserData", False
        DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", newDbPath, acForm, "UserForm", "UserForm", False
        MsgBox "The user database has been created.", vbInformation
    End If
    Set fd = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, Gord, this looks to be a pretty useful technique. I'll have to look into it further.